# How to define the multiplier range for variance test based outliers detection algorithm?

Tags: standard-deviation, mean, outliers, variance-test

I have a variance test based outliers detection algorithm. The algorithm is exposed with a visual application where the user can configure its parameters namely the multiplier.

The question is what is the range of values for the algorithm multiplier?

the algorithm basically is calculating the mean and standard deviation (sigma) of the data set and then comparing the dataset elements to the upper and lower bounds to flag an element as an outlier or not.

```
multiplier <- 2.3; 
upper_bound <- mean + multiplier * sigma; 
lower_bound <- mean - multiplier * sigma;
```

the evolution of the two functions upper_bound (red) and lower_bound(blue) with the multiplier values is as follows:

[image]

But this graph doesn't give any clue on what range to define. Do you have any idea how to define this range?

Comment: Do you know anything about the shape of the distribution of the $Y$-values?

Comment: actually, I don't have this luxury. The application should work for any distribution.

Comment: Then you might go with Chebychev's inequality (the finite sample version) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality It gives bounds for the probability to deviate more than $k$ standard deviations from the mean. If you know mean and standard deviation, you can derive the range based on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the outliers, you cannot use the distance of an observation to a model through a rule such as:

$$\frac{|\hat{\mu}-x_i|}{\times \hat{\sigma}},\;i=1,\ldots,n$$

if your estimates of $(\hat{\mu},\hat{\sigma})$ are the classical ones (the usual mean/standard deviation) because the fitting procedure you use to obtain them is itself liable to being pulled towards the outliers (this is called the masking effect).

One simple way to reliably detect outliers however is to use the general idea you suggested (distance from fit) but replacing the classical estimators by robust ones much less susceptible to be swayed by outliers. Below I present a general illustration of the idea. If you give more information about your specific problem I can append my answer to address the particulars of your situation.

An illustration: consider the following 20 observations 
drawn from a $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ (rounded to the second 
digit):

```
x<-c(-2.21,-1.84,-.95,-.91,-.36,-.19,-.11,-.1,.18,
.3,.31,.43,.51,.64,.67,.72,1.22,1.35,8.1,17.6)
```

(the last two really ought to be .81 and 1.76 but have
 been accidentally misstyped).

Using a outlier detection rule based on comparing the statistic

$$\frac{|x_i-\text{ave}(x_i)|}{\text{sd}(x_i)}$$

to the quantiles of a normal distribution would never 
lead you to suspect that 8.1 is an outlier, leading you 
to estimate the $\text{sd}$ of the 'trimmed' series to be
 2 (for comparison the raw, e.g. untrimmed, estimate of
 $\text{sd}$ is  4.35).

Had you used a robust statistic instead:

$$\frac{|x_i-\text{med}(x_i)|}{\text{mad}(x_i)}$$

and comparing the resulting robust $z$-scores to the 
choosen quantiles of a candidate distribution (typically the 
standard normal if you can assume the $x_i$'s to be 
symetrically distributed) you would have correctly 
 the last two observations as outliers (and correctly 
estimated the $\text{sd}$ of the trimmed series to be 
0.96).

Comment: In my case, I cannot assume that my distribution is normal or is not, and the outlier detection should work for all cases. In fact, I only have an idea about what data set to run the outlier detection on just after the user interaction. The variance test was the most general idea that doesn't require me to have previous knowledge of the distribution of my data. What I understand from your explanation is that I should replace comparing the distance with comparing the statistic, is that what you mean? and what is "med" and "mad"

Comment: med is median and mad is the median absolute deviation. Even then, you will find the the quantile of the normal are tilted to the conservative side (for symmetric distributions)